# How can I validate my REFERER URL with glob?

Tags: java, regex, referrer

I'm trying to check if my referrer String is coming from any URL with the format https://www.google.com/{{anything}}:

```
    String referrer = req.getHeader("REFERER");

    if (!(referrer.equals("https://www.google.com")) + createRegexFromGlob("*")) {
        System.out.println("The referrer is valid.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The referrer is not valid.");
    }
```

Here is the glob:

```
public static String createRegexFromGlob(String glob)
{
    String out = "^";
    for(int i = 0; i < glob.length(); ++i)
    {
        final char c = glob.charAt(i);
        switch(c)
        {
        case '*': out += ".*"; break;
        case '?': out += '.'; break;
        case '.': out += "\\."; break;
        case '\\': out += "\\\\"; break;
        default: out += c;
        }
    }
    out += '$';
    return out;
}
```

Does the referrer URL have to be a direct hit or will it automatically know if it's coming from the base URL, https://www.google.com?

I suppose I can just use `.contains` instead of making sure the string is equal to something plus a regular expression? Is there anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `.startsWith` instead?

Try

```
if (referrer.startsWith("https://www.google.com"))
```

Also, what on earth are are you doing with `createRegexFromGlob`? Simply match the URL with the following regex

```
^https:\/\/www\.google\.com.*$
```

Java code:

```
String pattern = "^https:\\/\\/www\\.google\\.com.*$";
if(referrer.matches(pattern))
```

`.contains` can be used but it'll also accept URLs like

```
http://example.com/https://www.google.com
```

Comment: And the regex is understood in the string?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Did you try `startsWith`?

Comment: Yes .startswith works. I was wondering if I can just ask if the url string equals the regex expression that you provided.

Comment: If you mean you'd like check using regex, I've added that in my answer.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!